# React Native Ios Build FBReactNativeSpec phasescriptexecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, release

While generating IOS build this error occurs when we add @react-native-firebase/messaging and @react-native-firebase/pushnotification. node version 16 macbook air 2021 M1 chip. Xcode 14.2[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBUSk.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmpWp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsWu3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBQL.jpg)

I tried deleting pod files reinstalling and everything i could find on the internet for this error.

Comment: Can you run your project through terminal and share the error in terminal?

Comment: thanks yakup but solved it the xcode was not picking up the path of node so ran nvm install default to link the node to where xcode picks up the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Xcode was not picking up the node path because i installed the node through nvm so i ran "nvm install default" so nvm can link the default path to where xcode detects it.